# Interfaces package: quickprofile on changefont

Tags: changes, interfaces

I'm sorry but I do not understand much English, so I do not understand how to use the command `\quickprofile` in the 'interfaces' package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{interfaces}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

{\changefont{shape=it}
  \lipsum[1]
}

{\changefont{size+ = 1}
  \lipsum[1]
}

{\quickprofile2{shape=bf}
  \lipsum[1]
}

\end{document}
```

Could someone show me an example please?

Comment: Can you make it clearer what you want to do with the command?

Comment: Actually I want to understand how it works, that's all!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `\quickprofile` command simply reports in the console output and the log file the result of doing *n* repetitions of the code of its argument.

e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{interfaces}
\begin{document}
\def\foo{This is some text.}
\quickprofile1000{\foo}
\end{document}
```

The output of the console of this run is:

```
Profiler: step 0
Profiler: step 1

... 

Profiler: step 998 
Profiler: step 999

(interfaces) quickprofile: Time elapsed for 1000 cycles: 0sec 13ms
```

This expands `\foo` 1000 times and reports the amount of time elapsed. I think it is only of practical use to developers who are concerned about the speed of complex code.  For end users it is likely to have little value.